# How to overwrite properties of a type with generics in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm building a Next.js app in TypesScript and one of the type is:

```
type GetStaticPropsContext<Q extends ParsedUrlQuery = ParsedUrlQuery, D extends PreviewData = PreviewData> = {
    params?: Q | undefined;
    preview?: boolean | undefined;
    previewData?: D | undefined;
    locale?: string | undefined;
    locales?: string[] | undefined;
    defaultLocale?: string | undefined;
}
```

I want to change it so that `locale`, `locales`, and `defaultLocale` are never `undefined` to avoid writing `as string` and `as string[]` castings everywhere since in my application, locales are always defined.

I tried creating a type like this

```
type LocaleConfig = {
  locale: string
  defaultLocale: string
  locales: string[]
}
```

And then just using

```
export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps = (
  context: GetStaticPropsContext & LocaleConfig
) { // do stuff }
```

But I am getting a `Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.` error.

I also tried to create an interface extending `GetStaticPropsContext` but unless I misunderstood how this works, I will also have to copy over the generics like this (which is not ideal):

```
export interface NewGetStaticPropsContext<
  Q extends ParsedUrlQuery = ParsedUrlQuery,
  D extends PreviewData = PreviewData
> extends GetStaticPropsContext {
  params?: Q | undefined
  previewData?: D | undefined
  locale: string
  defaultLocale: string
  locales: string[]
}
```

Comment: I do not get any error: https://tsplay.dev/WoaOPN What could be causing it?

Comment: I think you are right, the issue seems to be in a global declaration - so normally `GetStaticPropsContext & LocaleConfig` is the right approach?

Comment: Yes, I usually use this technique with `Required` and `Pick` utility types: https://tsplay.dev/mq1Jdm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What very probably happens is that `GetStaticProps` type is actually what causes the error message:

Should it look like:

```
type GetStaticProps = (context: GetStaticPropsContext) => void;
```

...then it is the assignment into `getStaticProps` variable of a function that has some required argument properties that TS does not like: you can assign a more "permissive" function (e.g. one that accepts optional arguments, into a stricter one, i.e. that accepts required arguments), but not the reverse.

```
type GetStaticPropsContext<Q extends ParsedUrlQuery = ParsedUrlQuery, D extends PreviewData = PreviewData> = {
  params?: Q | undefined;
  preview?: boolean | undefined;
  previewData?: D | undefined;
  locale?: string | undefined;
  locales?: string[] | undefined;
  defaultLocale?: string | undefined;
}

type LocaleConfig = {
  locale: string
  defaultLocale: string
  locales: string[]
}

export const getStaticProps = (
  context: GetStaticPropsContext & LocaleConfig
) => { } // Okay

type GetStaticProps = (context: GetStaticPropsContext) => void

const getStaticProps2: GetStaticProps = getStaticProps;
// Type '(context: GetStaticPropsContext & LocaleConfig) => void' is not assignable to type 'GetStaticProps'.
// Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
// Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgApygZwgEwKpQA2AigK7QCeyA3sgL4BQDoksiKqUEAbsBAO4AROGDg16TMBQAOKAOIQwAZVFhgCTgHtpmAMKbwEAB5gAPMWTHIIHJjQZs+ImUrIAvPay4CJclAoANMiCliYQNnacPHxCImIeUbwCwqIAfO40DMjI0hhwALaYAPwAXMgWAD7IpDYQMKC4ANxZOVxJ-KXIAEaamoQQcCDIVTU4dQ04zdnSbTEpcJ0hI7X1IE0thJoIcP2dmGBQoADmw9UrE1PIm9v9xWX7hyBHANoAuqej42uTLWPwpIQwAAZLY7CB7A7HD7nb7NRgMKSyZAgm4QfQgeonDzUDag-r3SFPX51OAA4F4iAEx5HXGozBU45vBjw4zSTRQMDIBAGfbII6KFQidRaHQZAAULW5hhMZQUylUwqg2j0BkgJmQADJkRT0ZiGABKdzpWh0ZAAejNyAA8gBrOAUSQyeQChUaJWijxiqVqsCyl1Ct3K9E+w1udLcTTAHBMKW8-nygMizAAJj9CbUgY9fP9GaTzQtyAAKk7kAByL2qqxpwW590q6WcrUosG64BHUPhyM4UvIYB2ECaTlwTCYNsgOBdfrIMCaacl0tymuK5WlgB0DALxaRpYeUOWfwmPb7yAHQ5HY4nU5nc+3u6ea43lq3KFLn1WuCP-cHyGHo6O48nFBr0RF87yOB8gA)

By saying that `getStaticProps2` function is of `GetStaticProps` type, it means that we could call it with an empty argument (all properties in `GetStaticPropsContext` are optional):

```
getStaticProps2({});
```

But if `getStaticProps` is assigned into it, some properties would become required...

---

As to transform a type so that some of its optional properties become required, indeed, using an intersection (`&`) is the appropriate technique.

You can even use a combination of [`Required`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#requiredtype) and [`Pick`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#picktype-keys) utility types to catch typos and ensure the exact same types:

```
type LocaleConfig = Required<Pick<GetStaticPropsContext, "locale" | "defaultLocale" | "locales">>
//   ^? { locale: string; defaultLocale: string; locales: string []; }

export const getStaticProps = (
  context: GetStaticPropsContext & LocaleConfig
) => {
  // do stuff
  const locale = context.locale
  //    ^? string
  const preview = context.preview
  //    ^? boolean | undefined
}

getStaticProps({
  locale: "locale",
  defaultLocale: "",
  //locales: [] // Error if any of the Required properties is missing
});
// Property 'locales' is missing in type '{ locale: string; defaultLocale: string; }' but required in type 'Required<Pick<GetStaticPropsContext<ParsedUrlQuery, PreviewData>, "locale" | "defaultLocale" | "locales">>'.
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgApygZwgEwKpQA2AigK7QCeyA3sgL4BQDoksiKqUEAbsBAO4AROGDg16TMBQAOKAOIQwAZVFhgCTgHtpmAMKbwEAB5gAPMWTHIIHJjQZs+ImUrIAvPay4CJclAoANMiCliYQNnacPHxCImIeUbwCwqIAfO40DMjI0hhwALaYAPwAXMgWAD7IpDYQMKC4ANxZOVxJ-KXIAEaamoQQcCDIVTU4dQ04zdnSbTEpcJ0hI7X1IE0thJoIcP2dmGBQoADmw9UrE1PIm9v9xWX7hyBHANoAuqej42uTLWPwpIQwAAZLY7CB7A7HD7nb7NRgMKSyZAgm4QfQgeonDwAJQgAEdSMAuDhTKh1ABrUwKZSqdRaHToyAmIIAImuYJZpxZfzgAOBoP6nKqbIFEEwLNSqQYAHppdlkAA9IpMYzSTRQMDIBAGfbII6KFQiOlQbR2DwACha2sMJjK1MNag0JoZBiZmoAZMjRejMQwAJTudLUFqy5A4TTIfakGAwK06zXs-oZa1ugB0iYgIbl8qVcZAupm0QEyddVlThfaWfliuV8P1NKNTtN5uD2QzZRFqJZAV+dV5gJRYI73azGcwZTeyFDAFEoCaoMhgDBkIMqJpl2AABYoXEEom4VraaBqMWLuz5YCYTDHBh0P3NUP049UADkY5fZ+QF6vUNAyERKAvrQ7aRpCTyNGGfZ8oO-T3GBRwQXQH5dKQmpcHuxKLkMAHIC+u6EsSpIUlSBq0k2Lo2mY6BeE4viUEEiRzHEqSshmQrINyUEDqK7GdmC4qSi+qYMEAA)